# String_split function is not splitting delimiters in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I am trying to split the values in LOB column, while keeping the first column intact using the script below

```
select * 
from [dbo].[ReqApp]
where lob in 
 (select value from string_split ('Staff;Wealth Management',';'))
```

The query returns this:

[image]

The desire outcome is this.

[image]

I am using SQL Server 2019. 
Please provide suggestions on how to modify my script to get the desired outcome.

Comment: While it's great that others have provided a working solution, you really NEED to understand why your query does not do what you expect if you want to write tsql effectively. If lob contains the value "x;y", it will never be in the set generated by splitting. E.g., "x;y" is not equal to "x" nor is it equal to "y".

Comment: @SMor please explain why my solution did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you want `apply`:

```
select ra.id, s.value as lob
from [dbo].[ReqApp] ra cross apply
     string_split(ra.lob, ';') s;
```

This produces the data you have.  Your query though has a `where`, suggesting that you want filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `cross apply`

```
SELECT id, value as lob 
FROM [dbo].[ReqApp]  
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(lob, ',');
```

Comment: What can I do if I had an additional column [deparments] with delimiters and desired the results? How would you make that happen?

[Department] = {HR; Payroll;Finance}