# How to get value using split string in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have value in a column like below ( space separated string )

```
1 4 7 5
4 5
1 4
1 3 4
```

I just need that 1 is 3 times,3 is 1 time, 4 is 4 times 5 is 2 times & 7 is 1 times.

Like below:

```
Value| count
-----+-------
 1   |   3 
 3   |   1 
 4   |   4 
 5   |   2 
 7   |   1
```

I have tried like this:

```
SELECT value  
FROM [dbo].tbl  
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT((SELECT DisCode FROM tbl), ' ');
```

but I get an error

> Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'

I have tried:
[String_split function is not splitting delimiters in SQL Server 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62313309/string-split-function-is-not-splitting-delimiters-in-sql-server-2019)
but did not get any solution.

Somebody asked about the lowest the compatibility level, but it's not possible for me to downgrade by server level because it's a running online server.(['STRING_SPLIT' is not a recognized built-in function name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37616831/string-split-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name) )

Please give me a possible solution.

Comment: `STING_SPLIT` is available in `SQL Server 2019`. Your compatibility level must be set as a much earlier version. `STRING_SPLIT` should be available from `SQL Server 2016` / Compatibility Level `130`

Comment: What version are you running `select @@version`? @Squirrel `STING_SPLIT` is certainly ***NOT*** available, `STRING_SPLIT` is available from 2016 already

Comment: My version is: Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) . I am unable to downgraded the compatibility level.

Comment: @Charlieface lol. Typo error

Comment: We are not asking you to downgrade the `compatibility level` but to change it to minimum 130 if you want to use the `STRING_SPLIT()`

Answer (score 2):

STING_SPLIT is available in `SQL Server 2019`. Your compatibility level must be set as a much earlier version. `STRING_SPLIT` should be available from SQL Server 2016 / Compatibility Level 130 onwards.

Also your query should be

```
SELECT  value, count(*)
FROM    tbl 
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT (DisCode, ' ')
GROUP BY value
```

[STRING_SPLIT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Still same: Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'.

Comment: what is your Compatibility Level  ?

Answer (score 0):

`STRING_SPLIT()` is available starting in SQL Server 2016, which means that it requires compatibility level 130 or higher (see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).

A database running on SQL Server 2019 can run with a variety of compatibility levels *even lower than 130*.  You can check the compatibility level of your database by using:

```
SELECT compatibility_level  
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = db_name();
```

If this is less than 130, then you will not have access to the function, unless you change the compatibility or create a new database with a higher compatibility level.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to SQL 2016 one way to split strings is/was to use a ['Tally' function or 'numbers' table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2663232/6748758) approach.  In this code the CTE 'numbers_cte' contains 20 rows.  The outer query uses CROSS JOIN to create up to 400 (20^2) rows (if more are needed then add more `CROSS JOIN`s, as needed). Using a row goal (`SELECT TOP(n)`) means the un-used rows are never generated so the query is very efficient.  Something like this

```
declare @txtTable   table(txt       varchar(50) not null)

insert @txtTable(txt) values 
('1 4 7 5'),
('4 5'),
('1 4'),
('1 3 4');

with numbers_cte(n) as (
    select * from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),
                          (11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20)) v(n))
select v.chr, count(*) as char_count
from @txtTable t
     cross apply (select top(len(t.txt)) row_number() over (order by (select null)) as N
                  from numbers_cte n1
                       cross join numbers_cte n2) fn
     cross apply (values (substring(t.txt, N, 1))) v(chr)
where
  v.chr <> ' '
group by v.chr;
```

```
chr char_count
1   3
3   1
4   4
5   2
7   1
```